# Interpreter and Compiler

Tags: interpreter, compiler-theory, java-compiler-api

Can any one help me in figuring out what  compilers and interpreters are? And what their difference is ? Appreciate it if explained for Java beginner as I am one.

Comment: What have you found so far ? What docs do you rely on to perform your own analysis ? How would people here help you *improve* your existing understanding based on your own in-depth study ? You're asking for help, but you do not seem to have tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically (very basically), a compiler build your program. It translates your java code into something the computer understands. An interpreter runs your program.

Both can catch errors but they are different types. Compilation errors can be syntax, semantic or logical errors. On the other hand, errors from your interpreter are only known once you run the program.

For example, if you have an array that contains 3 fruits like this:

```java
String[] fruits = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry"];
```

And you try this:

```java
System.out.println(fruits[4]);
```

The compiler won't get the error, because there are no syntax errors (everything seems fine at compile-time) but once you run the program, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which is a `RuntimeException` caught by the interpreter.